# Date value in mysql tables changes while exporting mysql db

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, export

I am exporting mysql table to setup it on live, but while exporting DB I noticed that my *date column value is changing*.. If it was "**2007-06-11 00:00:00**" earlier then after export it is now changed to "**2007-06-10 18:30:00**",

why this is so?
anybody have idea about this?

Comment: yes data type is 'timestamp' , I am seeing changes in export file as well as on new server, I am exporting data through phpmyadmin -> export tab, mysql version is 5.0.8

Comment: is there any way to correct that data loaded on new server over there only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bug #13052](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13052) existed in versions of MySQL prior to 5.0.15, in which dump files expressed `TIMESTAMP` columns in the server's timezone but did not include a `SET TIME_ZONE` command to ensure anyone (or any subsequent server) reading the dump file understood that; without such a command, receiving servers assume that any `TIMESTAMP` values are in its default timezone.

Therefore a transfer between servers in timezones offset by 18:30 (e.g. from South Australia to California) would lead to the behaviour you observe.

Solutions to this problem, in some vague order of preference, include:

1. Upgrade the version of mysqldump on the original server to 5.0.15 or later (will result in the dumpfile expressing all `TIMESTAMP` values in UTC, with a suitable `SET TIME_ZONE` statement at the start);
2. Prior to export (or import), change the global [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) variable on the source (or destination) server, so that it matches the setting on the other server at the time of import (or export):

   ```
   SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles'; -- ('Australia/Adelaide')
   ```
3. `UPDATE` the data after the fact, applying MySQL's [`CONVERT_TZ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function:

   ```
   UPDATE my_table
   SET    my_column = CONVERT_TZ(
                        my_column,
                        'America/Los_Angeles',
                        'Australia/Adelaide'
                      );
   ```

If using either solution 2 or solution 3, beware to use the *exact* timezone of the relevant server's `time_zone` variable, in such a manner as to include any daylight savings time.  However, note that as documented under [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time-zone-support.html): "*Named time zones can be used only if the time zone information tables in the mysql database have been created and populated.*"  The article goes on to explain how to create and populate the time zone information tables.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can correct the uploaded data on live server?

Answer (score 3):

before export database just follow below steps:

> export with custom option
>
> uncheck the checkbox below
>
> ```
> Dump TIMESTAMP columns in UTC (enables TIMESTAMP columns to be dumped and reloaded between servers in different time zones)
> ```

show in below image
[image]